# nvidia-setting not restoring settings properly after login

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, xfce

I finally was able to setup a triple-head setup on a nvidia card using nvidia-settings and arrange the monitors accordingly.

I also used the option to save the settings to the Xorg.conf - but when I restart the computer, the monitor configuration is wrong (one monitor overlaps with the other one).

The monitors are all the same type.

Comment: have you run `nvidia-settings` with sudo privilege? `gksu nvidia-settings`

Comment: @Web-E: When using the save to xorg option, it asked me the sudo password - isn't that enought?

Comment: try once with `gksu nvidia-settings` / `sudo nvidia-settings`. I used to have this problem in my old system (don't know how it behaves now).

Comment: @Web-E: tried it know - the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like both XFCE and nvidia settings (or the standard xorg config) tried to apply settings here.

The XFCE settings are wrong.

After some debugging concerning another problem ([Why does XFCE ignore my preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284691/why-does-xfce-ignore-my-preferences)) I found out that I have to delete `.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml` to solve that problem - but this also solved the problem with applying the right screen settings after login.