# Why does XFCE ignore my preferences?

Tags: 12.10, xfce, settings

After re-configuring the screen setup (nvidia x settings), my XFCE starts in the default styling and shortcuts such as Alt+F2 are not working anymore.

Whenever I check the shortcuts under settings Keyboard -> Shortcuts they are correct.

When I change to another theme under Apperance, nothing changes.

What can be the be the reason for this?

How can I track down the problem further?

I would be happy for any small hint.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with XFCEs settings daemon.

It can be debugged as described in the [XFCE docs](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/xfsettingsd):

If the `--sync` parameter is added, too, the daemon seems to continue on errors:

`XFSETTINGSD_DEBUG=1 xfsettingsd --replace --no-daemon --sync`

Update on my case:

- When started with the `--sync` option, the settings actually get applied and there is an error printed with the screen configuration.

I was finally able to solve this problem by deleting the file `.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`